# PHP MYSQL JAVA get byte from blob error

Tags: java, php, mysql, fingerprint

I am developing a java applcation where I have a database stored at some website hosting server (000webhost) and I have written code to fetch data from database server (MySQL) in PHP file hosted as website.
Here is the code for the same:

```
//http://mahaweb.ml/java.php
<?php
require "connect.php";
$db = $_POST["db"];
mysqli_select_db($con,$db);
$mysql_qry = $_POST["query"];   
$result = mysqli_query($con,$mysql_qry);    
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){                  // for each row in results
        foreach($row as $value){                           // for each column in row
                echo $value.'|';
        }   
    }
}
else
    echo 'null';
?>
```

The java code to read data from the php file:

```
public static String getData(String query,String db){
        HttpURLConnection conn=null;
        String inputLine = null,result = null;
        try{
            URL url=new URL("http://mahaweb.ml/java.php");                
            conn=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");    
            String postData = URLEncoder.encode("db","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(db,"UTF-8")+"&"+URLEncoder.encode("query","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
            OutputStream out=conn.getOutputStream();    
            out.write(postData.getBytes());    
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));                
            while((inputLine=in.readLine())!=null){                             
                    StringBuffer tmp1 = new StringBuffer(inputLine);
                    tmp1.deleteCharAt(tmp1.length()-1);
                    result = tmp1.toString();        
            }
            in.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        if(result.equals("null"))
            return null;
        return result;
}
```

I am storing fingerprints on database using a blob column that contains fingerprint values in byte format.
When I am using jdbc connector to get data from database and matching that data with fingerprints, it matchs successfully,the code is here for the same:

```
Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dlap_application",user,pass);
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select fingerscan from login where empID like 'MH1200001'");            
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next())          
            ISOTemplate = rs.getBytes("fingerscan");            
        ps.close();
        rs.close();
        con.close();
        int ret = mfs100.AutoCapture(data, timeout,  false, false);
        if(ret == 0){
            int score = 0;
            score = mfs100.MatchISO(data.ISOTemplate(), ISOTemplate);                
            System.out.println("Score:"+score);
            if(score > 14000){
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Success:"+score, ButtonType.OK);
            alert.show();
            }else if (score >= 0 && score < 14000) {
                Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, "Failure:"+score, ButtonType.OK);
                alert.show();
            }   
        }
        else{
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION, "Return Code:"+ret+" "+mfs100.GetLastError(), ButtonType.OK);
        alert.show();
        }
```

But when I am using PHP code to fetch data from database, it gets me the data but in string format.
I am converting that string data into bytes and trying to match it with new fingerprint data but not getting any success because the data is lost during string to bye conversion.
So, how do I get data from database using PHP in byte format without losing the data?

Comment: What actual error do you get?  Is there an exception/stack trace?  Is it just bad output?  What is the output?

Comment: Sorry, please check the edit!!

Comment: I think your question is much better now.  However I don't know PHP well, so we'll have to wait for a PHP expert to answer.

Comment: @markspace "Your question is much better now" - Thanks

Comment: First of all your PHP MySQL interaction is *extremely* insecure if you're allow users to post whole queries. What happens if they post a DELETE or DROP? Second, instead of storing BLOB's (extremely inefficient among other things) you should store a URL to the image.

Comment: @Jay I have restricted the delete and drop for all other users than root, they only can insert, update and select from a particular database table. Blob I am using because I am storing fingerprint data that is in byte format. I am not storing image or url.

Comment: Are you familiar with SQL Injection?

Comment: @Jay not much, a little theory only, but security is not a concern for me right now. I just want to extract data and match fingerprints. Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: I hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later? What if my query is `SELECT * from table; DROP table;`? That's a small example of SQL Injection. It looks like what you allow, but it is so much more. I have already said what I would do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644397/php-mysql-java-get-byte-from-blob-error?noredirect=1#comment74337685_43644397)